# modeling a video playlist feature issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm trying to model a playlist feature in rails

my models:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :playlists
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :playlists
 has_many :videos ,through: :playlists
end

class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
  has_one :user
end
```

joint_table playlist_videos

```
  create_table "playlists_videos", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "video_id"
    t.integer "playlist_id"
  end
```

everything works great in the console ,i can push a video to a specific playlist via the console, but what I'm trying to figure out how to write a method to actually push the video already created by selecting the playlist via a select_tag or check_box_tag via either a link or a button .I get stuck here. don't know how to proceed for make it work in the UI . Appdemo  [Here](http://demo-box-31842.use1.actionbox.io:3000/).

in video controller , my add_to method

```
 def add_to_playlist(video_id, playlist_id)
    @video = Video.find_by(params[:id])
    @playlist = current_user.playlists.find_by(params[:id])
    @video.playlists << @playlist
    playlist.save
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saving the playlist and not the video you should push the the video into the playlist.  Also make sure that you're calling save on `@playlist` and not `playlist`.

```
@playlist.videos << @video
@playlist.save
```

Comment: When i do it that way in the console , ive encountered an error . Probably theree some issues with my associations that i have to fix to make it work .

Comment: Can you post the error and stack trace?  Or maybe you need to save the video too?